# String allocation syntax error

Tags: python, escaping

I have the following code snippet, but there is a syntax error which I am not able to trace.

```
space = "space"
title = "new"
content = "content"
command ='confluence --action storePage --space \"' + space + '\" --title \"' + title '\" --parent \"@home\" --content \"' + content + '\" --noConvert --server <server> --user <user> --password <password>'
```

The syntax error as pointed out by the python interpreter is at **--content \" '**.

Any help in pointing it out is appreciated.

Comment: If you are running a command, take a look in subprocess library, it will make sure it to escape all arguments.

Comment: Okay, I was using os.system(), but I will take a look at it, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot a + after title

```
command ='confluence --action storePage --space \"' + space + '\" --title \"' + title + '\" --parent \"@home\" --content \"' + content + '\" --noConvert --server <server> --user <user> --password <password>'
```

Comment: Yes! Thanks! I don't know why I didn't notice it!

Answer (score 2):

In your case you can use string formatting like this:

```
space = "space"
title = "new"
content = "content"
command_string = "programm --space %(space) --title %(title) --content %(content)"
command = command_string % {'space': space, 'title': title, 'content': content}
```

Answer (score 2):

Others already pointed out that you forgot a `+` after `title`.
Using a less error-prone notation might help to avoid this kind of mistake:

```
space = "space"
title = "new"
content = "content"
command ='confluence --action storePage --space \"{}\" --title \"{}\" --parent \"@home\" --content \"{}\" --noConvert --server <server> --user <user> --password <password>'.format(space, title, content)
```